# Shell sh , syntax while(condition)

Tags: linux, shell, while-loop, sh

I am testing a simple program shell(sh).

I am using while loop but it show an error.

> ./essai.sh: line 5: test: too many arguments

This is the code:

```
#!/bin/sh

numero=1
max=3
while test [ $numero -le $max ]
do
ping -c 2 127.0.0.1
numero=$(($numero + 1)) 
printf $numero
sleep 5
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Condition statement is wrong 
change condition from

```
while test [ $numero -le $max ]
```

to

```
while [ $numero -le $max ]
```

Comment: It is very sensitive to spaces... I tested this solution before but I did not pay attention to spaces.
Thank you anyway, it works now !

Comment: Or simply remove the square brackets: `while test $numero -le $max`

Comment: Or use parentheseis and make the comparision look more natural: `while ((numero <= max))`  .... OOPS, just noticed: We have Posix Shell here, not bash. In this case, this alternative wouldn't work.

Answer (score 3):

"[]" means "test", So you can change that line to

```
  while test  $numero -le $max
```

or

```
  while [ $numero -le $max ]
```

BTW: the spaces between "[]" and conditional expression is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

The test keyword has to be removed:

```
while [ $numero -le $max ]
```

Do you know also

```
for numero in $(seq 1 3) ; do echo $numero ; done
```